Why is my float:left and float:none exactly the same, and not far enough to the left/not centered
I'm using neocities to make a website and so far I have found that using div.nameofdiv (what every website I've tried says to do) doesn't work, but #nameofdiv does, I'm trying to make a site that includes three side-by-side panels, but float:left and float:none are in the exact same place, which is not even the end of the screen, but just off centre. Float:right works is towards the right but still really not far enough to the right, but more centre-right.
First I used https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp as a guide, and added the Float:left property to the div that I wanted to be on the left. I expected it to move next to the middle column on the left, but nothing happened.
Here is the code:
#leftlinks {
    float: left;
    background-color:LemonChiffon;   
    border: 3px solid;
    border-color:darkgrey;
    color:#333333;
    padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
    width: 33%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;

screenshot of the website 
Here is the linked HTML:
<div id="leftlinks">   
  <h1>
    Links! (to be added)
  </h1>
   
</div>

